# Mac App Bundle cannot access USB devices when hardened for notarization

Tags: macos, usb, notarize

We have written a native application that accesses an USB card-terminal through some closed-source libraries. The application is written with C/C++ and cross-platform compatible (already working on Linux and Windows) and using Gtk3 as UI. Therefore we're not using XCode at all. Furthermore, we use LIBMICROHTTPD, GNUTLS, JSONCPP, and some other stuff and we linked also LIBASAN<sup>1</sup>. The application runs fine as app bundle and also fine when the executable is not signed **hardened** with `--options=runtime`. But for getting a successful notarization we have to sign the executable with `--options=runtime` and this breaks the application. It launches fine but hangs/loops during the actual USB access.

Providing you with a minimum viable example is hard with the closed-source libraries between us and the USB card-terminal. But I try to show you what we're doing:

```bsh
    codesign -f -s "macosnewbie" carrier.app/Contents/MacOS/* --timestamp --options=runtime
    codesign -f -s "macosnewbie" carrier.app/Contents/libs/lib* --timestamp
    codesign -f -s "macosnewbie" carrier.app/Contents/libs/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-* --timestamp
    codesign -f -s "macosnewbie" carrier.app/Contents/Resources/* --timestamp
    codesign -f -s "macosnewbie" --options=runtime --entitlements entitlements.plist carrier.app --deep
```

The first `codesign` is crucial for the notarization but breaks the application. When signed without `--options=runtime` it works fine. We also zip the app bundle notarize and staple it.

```bsh
    xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "19" -f carrier.zip -u "me@ourcompancy.de"
    xcrun stapler staple carrier.app
```

**Info.plist**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Carrier Card Terminal</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>carrier</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>de.ourcompany.www</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Carrier</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>carrier.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.01</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>IFMajorVersion</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>IFMinorVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

**entitlements.plist**

```xml
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
        <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key> <!-- usb access -->
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key> <!-- internal webserver --> 
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key> <!-- internal webserver -->
        <true/>
         </dict>
    </plist>
```

What I'm missing and doing wrong?

Below I've added the complete directory structure of the app bundle to give you an overview. If necessary I can also provide you the actual executable app bundle, but it is useless without an attached, compatible hardware terminal.
Thank you

<sup>1</sup> We have some sort of undefined behavior on MacOS (or with CLANG?) and linking with LIBASAN has proven as a workaround.

```bsh
carrier.app
└── Contents
├── Info.plist
├── MacOS
│   └── carrier
├── Resources
│   ├── carrier.icns
│   ├── server.key
│   └── server.pem
├── _CodeSignature
│   └── CodeResources
└── libs
├── gdk-pixbuf-2.0
│   └── 2.10.0
│   └── loaders # loaders.cache is missing here...
│   ├── libpixbufloader-ani.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-bmp.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-gif.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-icns.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-ico.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-jpeg.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-png.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-pnm.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-qtif.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-tga.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-tiff.so
│   ├── libpixbufloader-xbm.so
│   └── libpixbufloader-xpm.so
├── libBrpDriver.dylib
├── libalwa_driver.dylib
├── libatk-1.0.0.dylib
├── libatkmm-1.6.1.dylib
├── libbrp_lib.dylib
├── libcairo-gobject.2.dylib
├── libcairo.2.dylib
├── libcairomm-1.0.1.dylib
├── libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
├── libepoxy.0.dylib
├── libffi.6.dylib
├── libfontconfig.1.dylib
├── libfreetype.6.dylib
├── libfribidi.0.dylib
├── libgdk-3.0.dylib
├── libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.0.dylib
├── libgdkmm-3.0.1.dylib
├── libgio-2.0.0.dylib
├── libgiomm-2.4.1.dylib
├── libglib-2.0.0.dylib
├── libglibmm-2.4.1.dylib
├── libgmodule-2.0.0.dylib
├── libgmp.10.dylib
├── libgnutls.30.dylib
├── libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
├── libgraphite2.3.2.1.dylib
├── libgtk-3.0.dylib
├── libgtkmm-3.0.1.dylib
├── libharfbuzz.0.dylib
├── libhogweed.4.5.dylib
├── libidn2.0.dylib
├── libintl.8.dylib
├── libjsoncpp.21.dylib
├── libmicrohttpd.12.dylib
├── libnettle.6.5.dylib
├── libp11-kit.0.dylib
├── libpango-1.0.0.dylib
├── libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
├── libpangoft2-1.0.0.dylib
├── libpangomm-1.4.1.dylib
├── libpcre.1.dylib
├── libpixman-1.0.dylib
├── libpng16.16.dylib
├── libpsl.5.dylib
├── libsigc-2.0.0.dylib
├── libsoup-2.4.1.dylib
├── libsqlite3.0.dylib
├── libtasn1.6.dylib
└── libunistring.2.dylib

8 directories, 68 files
```

Comment: Did you resolve this. I am also facing this issue

Comment: Sadly not! We have now access to a part (not all!) of the code used in the closed-source libraries and hope to be able to debug it soon. Apples support confirmed that all “looks fine” and they assume an issue in the closed-source libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to get ours to work by adding the following entitlement.

```
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the issue finally! Do you know how to detect such required entitlements without knowing before? I've tried it with "Console" but didn't succeed.